# Why would one declare a Java interface method as abstract?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, abstract

I used the "pull interface" refactoring feature of Eclipse today to create an interface based on an existing class. The dialog box offered to create all the new methods of the new interface as "abstract" methods.

What would be the benefit of that?

I thought that the fact that you were allowed to declare interface methods as abstract was a superfluous and harmless feature of the language that is not particularly encouraged.

Why would Eclipse support such a style, or why would someone voluntarily choose to do so?

Clarification: I am not asking why interface methods are abstract, that is obvious. I am asking why one would explicitly choose to mark them as abstract since if they're in an interface they are abstract anyway.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1), the `abstract` keyword for interfaces is obsolete and should no longer be used. (Section 9.1.1.1)

That said, with Java's propensity for backwards compatibility, I really doubt it will ever make a difference whether the `abstract` keyword is present.

Comment: That was my understanding (though I was not familiar with the specific JLS section). I'm wondering why Eclipse would offer me the option of creating an obselete marking...

Comment: Got me. Someone somewhere must of decided it was a desirable "feature" and put it in. You know, one of those wily open-source types :)

Comment: Although this is the top-rated answer, it is referring to the wrong section of the Specification; 9.1.1.1 is describing the `abstract` keyword on the declaration of the interface itself, not on its members. @Will's answer below is correct and also contains valid link sources.

Answer (score 40):

"The benefice of that" (adding abstract on interface methods declaration) in eclipse would be an old compatibility issue with [jdt eclipse compiler in jdk1.3](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11435)

> Since 1.4, jdk libraries are no longer containing default abstract methods (on abstract classes implementing interfaces).
>   This is fooling the Eclipse 1.3 compiler diagnosis since their implementation is relying on their existence.
>   Note that Javac 1.3 would refuse altogether to perform against 1.4 libraries (using -bootclasspath option).

Since the Eclipse compiler is likely to be in 1.4 compliance level (see `Workbench>Preferences>Java>Compiler>JDK Compliance`), or use at least 1.3 class libraries if using 1.3 compliance mode, the presence of "abstract" is not required in most of the current eclipse projects.

Comment: Good find. So it's functionality to work around a no-longer existent problem in the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: @jdmichal: exactly, and it is also a more accurate answer to Uri's question.

Answer (score 40):

From the [Java SE 7 JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4) (Java Language Specification): "It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the public and/or abstract modifier for a method declared in an interface."

For [Java SE 5.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#9.4):  "For compatibility with older versions of the Java platform, it is permitted but discouraged, as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the abstract modifier for methods declared in interfaces."

Answer (score 9):

According to JLS methods in interfaces are abstract by default, so the keyword is redundant. Knowing this, I'd never use it to "avoid presentational clutter".

Comment: This should be the right answer. Here's an updated [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) - see "note" section

Comment: The JLS does not say the keyword is obsolete for methods in interfaces. It says "It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the public and/or abstract modifier for a method declared in an interface." [JLS #9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4).

Comment: @EJP I didn't say that the JLS stated the keyword would be obsolete, this was my personal opinion ;) BTW they note this keyword being "redundant" which is not quite the same as obsolete, in this you're right of course. Now that I know I'll edit the answer to clarify this.