# In Java, when should I use an abstract method in an interface?

Tags: java, interface, coding-style, abstract-methods

I have the following interface in Java

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public abstract void foo();
    public void bar();
}
```

What is the difference between foo() and bar()?
When should I use abstract?

Both seem to accomplish what I want unless I'm missing something subtle?

**Update** Duplicate of [Why would one declare a Java interface method as abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641536/why-would-one-declare-a-java-interface-method-as-abstract)

Comment: It does compile; just that the abstract modifier is redundant.

Comment: Looks like a dupe of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641536/why-would-one-declare-a-java-interface-method-as-abstract

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There isn't any functional difference. No implementation is ever provided in a java interface so all method declarations are implicitly abstract.

See [1]: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

A direct quote form the above:

> Note: All of the methods in an interface (see the Interfaces section) are implicitly abstract, so the abstract modifier is not used with interface methods (it could be—it's just not necessary).

Answer (score 17):

Interface methods are both `public` and `abstract` by default. There's no difference between `foo()` and `bar()` and you can safely remove all `public` and `abstract` keywords.

Comment: I wouldn't say "by default" but rather "implicitly". "By default" might be interpreted as other options exist besides "public abstract".

Answer (score 5):

You're not missing anything. From the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html):

> Every method declaration in the body
>   of an interface is implicitly
>   abstract, so its body is always
>   represented by a semicolon, not a
>   block.
>
> Every method declaration in the body
>   of an interface is implicitly public.

In other words, you can omit the `public` as well as the `abstract` on the interface methods.

Answer (score 4):

It's redundant (there's no difference between the two declarations) and explicitly discouraged in [section 9.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.4) of the Java Language specification:

> For compatibility with older versions
>   of the Java platform, it is permitted
>   but discouraged, as a matter of style,
>   to redundantly specify the abstract
>   modifier for methods declared in
>   interfaces.

And `public` is similarly unnecessary and discouraged:

> It is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the 
>   public modifier for interface methods.

I don't know why `public` is *strongly* discouraged but `abstract` is just discouraged...

Comment: Just speculation... but for the abstract keyword - it's redundant and pretty obvious - there's no implementation there.  It's easy to recognize if you know the general concept of interfaces.  If the public modifier were specified it might lead someone who doesn't know public is the default (and only) option to think they can change the access modifier to something else.

Answer (score 3):

Both accomplish the same, since all methods in an interface are abstract.

Answer (score 2):

`abstract` in this scenario is unnecessary (as is marking methods in interfaces as `public`).

You would *instead* use this on a method in an abstract class in order to enforce its overriding by a subclass.

Answer (score 2):

There no are difference between declarations. Conceptually, all methods in an interface are abstract.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference. All the methods in a java interface are always abstract.

See the first note at this link :
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 0):

Both foo() and bar() are abstract as they are declared inside an interface. The abstract word you used here is of no significance - you better remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces in java are equal "somehow" to a fully abstract classes, so adding the "abstract" keyword to a method declaration in an interface has nothing to do with the method!