# Do we need to declare interface methods as abstract

Tags: java, interface, abstract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java abstract interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202616/java-abstract-interface)

```
public interface Foo {
   abstract public void bar();
}
```

I guess we don't need to declare `abstract` as well as public in the above `interface`. Will the compiler catch this is as a warning or is it allowed by the compiler.

Comment: Maybe you could just try ?

Comment: The `abstract` modifier for Interfaces is [obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641536/why-would-one-declare-a-java-interface-method-as-abstract).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to, every interface method is implicitly `abstract`. It will not be a mistake to write it though.

Answer (score 7):

In an interface the the modifiers `public` and `abstract` are implied for methods, similarly for fields `public` `static` and `final` are implied. For inner classes `static` is implied.

Answer (score 6):

It is allowed. `public` and `abstract` are automatically added to every `interface` method.

Answer (score 3):

For interface methods, it is not necessary to declare **public and abstract**
 by default those are **public and abstract**

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary but it won't hurt to write it. These modifiers are implied.

I like to do it so everything is explicit and may help other programmers that will work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to declare abstract inside the interface. The complier can pass it.

```
public interface foointerface {

    abstract public void foo();

    public void bar();
}
```

But there is no point to declare in abstract since
we would not implement or allow to implement methods inside interface.