# what is a abstract method on a interface in java

Tags: java, interface, ejb, abstract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would one declare a Java interface method as abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641536/why-would-one-declare-a-java-interface-method-as-abstract)

I found the following code in one of our ejb interfaces. Does anyone know what the abstract does in the interface? If you do please also explain why it might be needed or provide a reference to read about it =)

```
@Local
public interface IDomasOrderProcessor {

    public abstract void executeOrderLines(List<OrderLine> lines);
    public abstract void setupJob(List<OrderLine> lines);
    public abstract void setupJob(OrderLine line);
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`abstract` is redundant in this case. All methods defined on an `interface` are `public` and `abstract` by definition.

Excerpt [Java Language Specification section 9.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.4)

> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   abstract, so its body is always represented by a semicolon, not a
>   block.
>
> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   public.

Comment: So is "public", in this case, incidentally. Which is to say that you can drop both and it will do the same thing.

It's possible that the code was originally an abstract class that got refactored.

Comment: Indeed, `public` as well. I added that to the answer, as my first was somewhat terse.

Comment: Since Java 8 interfaces can have methods with implementation. These are called default methods. Default methods can be added to an interface without affecting the classes that already implement the interface.

Answer (score 17):

Both `public` and `abstract` modifiers are implicit in interfaces and should be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

A method in an interface is public and abstract by definition. I have heard some people say they feel that explicitly declaring them like that makes it clearer, but to me it seems like extra noise.

Comment: It's certainly noise. (I had actually been programming for years in Java before I realised that the `public` was redundant.)

Answer (score 3):

As per [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.1.1.1)
document all the methods of `interface` is `public` and `abstract`, so there is no mean to define explicitly `abstract` method inside the `interface`.